# How to make "liftM2 (+) (T 1) (T 2)" working to produce "T 3" for "newtype T = T Int"

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

I have a type `T` defined as below and I want to wrap an integer in it.

```
newtype T = T Int
-- liftM2 (+) (T 1) (T 2)    -- error: `T' is not an instance of Monad
```

Now if I want to wrap an operation the values in the wrappers and return a similar the result like what `liftM*` does, just as shown in above code, but it doesn't work. I expect a group of functions that act like `myLiftT2` below but apply more generally.

```
myLiftT2 :: (Int -> Int -> Int) -> T -> T -> T
myLiftT2 f (T a) (T b) = T $ f a b

myLiftT2 (+) (T 1) (T 2)     -- `T 3'
```

I know I can define it as a Monad or an Applicative and actually that works good:

```
newtype T a = T a

instance Monad T where
  (T a) >>= f = f a
  return      = T

liftM2 (+) (T 1) (T 2)        -- produces `(T 3)' as expect
```

Considering the unnecessarity, I just don't want to add a polymorphism parameter `a` after the type because `T` should only wrap integers.

I am curious how people usually deal with, or circumvent, this inconvenience. Thanks.

Comment: I usually add the type parameter.  Sometimes it opens up possibilities that I hadn't thought about.  But it really depends on what the purpose of `T` is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype T  = T Int deriving (Show, Eq, Num)
```

Demo in ghci:

```
ghci> (T 1) + (T 2)
T 3
```

I don't feel there is a need for making it as an instance of `Monad`, if you just want to sum them up.